# 51Degrees Mobile Redirect with formsAuthentications

Tags: asp.net-mvc, 51degrees

I have a MVC project (.net fw 4.5) with forms authentication configured in web.config. When browsing from desktop devices all is working great; the user is being redirected to Login view. I installed '51Degrees' from 'Nuget' and set up the configuration as stated in their site. Also, I added 3 mobile views in the Home folder named: Index.iphone, Index.android and Index.mobile which I want the user to be redirected to them when browsing from mobile / tablet devices (depend on the device type)

My problem is that the login view is called first when browsing from mobile/tablet devices and after successful login the Index.mobile is always being called. I don't want the login view to load but instead I would like to show the respective view (based on device(s) type) which has a corresponding link to download the app (google play / app store).

Please your help.

I deleted the redirect section in 51Degrees config file. 
'Detector' HttpModule exists in my web config (Nuget added this automatically during 51 Degrees installation.)
I have a .dat file in my App_Data folder.
I have added DefaultDisplayMode options for android, iphone and mobile (as stated in 51Degrees site) in Application_Start in Global.asax file.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

A good example to look at of usage with MVC is on the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/51Degrees/dotNET-Device-Detection) within the Examples directory. The BaseController's Initialise method uses a Device model to set relevant properties for the device which can then be accessed through the ViewBag. So in your login view you can use something along the lines of

```
if( ViewBag.Device.PlatformName == "Android" )
{
    return Redirect("/AndroidApp");
}
else if
...
else
{
    return View();
}
```

Is this the sort of thing you were wanting?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Currently the logic has changed and the website is not mobile adjusted. I ended up checking for mobile only and redirect the user to the right area.